# Using a loop to rar multiple subfolders in a main folder

Tags: loops, batch-file, rar

I have a main folder with 3 subfolders ...

- **C:\Users\Admin\Folder**

  - Folder1
  - Folder2
  - Folder3

I want that the batch script grabs the first subdirectory `Folder1`, copy it to another location, for example `C:\Temp\Folder` and than *WinRAR* starts to archive `Folder1`. After copying `Folder1` to another location it can be deleted in the main folder.

After *WinRAR* finished archiving `Folder1` can also be deleted in `C:\Temp\Folder`. So only the .rar files remain.

Then the script starts from new with `Folder2` and do the same as with `Folder1`.

So far I have only this and do not really know how to implement the above.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -mt5 -v50M -r -df "NAME-OF-THE-RAR-FILE" "C:\Users\Admin\Folder\*.*"
```

Comment: What is the `first` subdirectory? The following description is unclear: `after copy Folder 1 have to be delete in the main folder and then rar the Folder`.

Comment: For example:

in "C:\Users\Admin\Folder\" are the sub folders 1-3

"Folder1
Folder2
Folder3"
...

With "after copy Folder 1" I mean that after the sub folder 1 is copy to the new directory "c:\temp\Folder" for the Rar process, it can be delete in the main folder "C:\Users\Admin\Folder"

Comment: Have it adjusted upwards and hope is now understandable. regs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, type and execute `for /?` and read help output for this command. The option `/D` is explained already on first help page which is for executing commands on each subdirectory of a directory.

The batch file below archives each subfolder in `C:\Users\Admin\Folder` using console version of *WinRAR* with command **m** (move = archive and delete on success) instead of command **a** with switch **-df**.

```
@echo off
for /D %%F in ("C:\Users\Admin\Folder\*") do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -mt5 -r -tl -v50M -y "%%~F.rar" "%%~F\"
    rd "%%~F"
)
```

So the result is

- **C:\Users\Admin\Folder**
  Folder1.rar
  Folder2.rar
  Folder3.rar

The folder can contain even more files after archiving and deletion of the folders depending on size of all files of the folders and how much 50 MB volumes are necessary to archive each folder.

The folder name `Folder1` is not included in file `Folder1.rar` because of the backslash in last parameter `"%%~F\"` at end of third line.

The batch file can be even easier if folder name `Folder1` should be also included in the archive file `Folder1.rar`

```
@echo off
for /D %%F in ("C:\Users\Admin\Folder\*") do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -mt5 -r -tl -v50M -y "%%~F.rar" "%%~F"
)
```

I don't think that copying each folder to a temporary folder just for archiving is necessary here.

Comment: Thank you first, now I have this `c:
cd \Users\Admin\Folder
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -mt5 -m1 -v100M -r -df "Description" "C:\Users\Admin\NewFolder\*.*`

I try that winrar only grab Folder1 to split it in a new folder `\Users\Admin\NewFolder`  than delete Folder1 `-df` under `\Users\Admin\Folder` so there remain Folder2, Folder3 and `start my.bat` again to do his job with the next folder (Folder2) ...