# Compress only first subFolder in mainFolder to a new folder

Tags: batch-file, compression, directory, rar

Using the *WinRAR* command line (`C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe`), what I'm trying to do is compress a single folder in a main folder (`C:\Users\%username%\desktop\mainFolder`) to a new folder (`C:\Users\%username%\desktop\newFolder`) and delete the single folder after compression in the main folder.

So that **ONLY** the first subfolder is compressed every time I start the .bat

- **C:\Users\***%username%***\mainFolder**

  - singleFolder1
  - singleFolder2
  - singleFolder3

So far that does only work for all folders which are in the main folder

```
c:
cd \Users\%username%\Desktop\newFolder
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -mt5 -m1 -v50M -r "!_RndAlphaNum!" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\mainFolder\
```

The `!_RndAlphaNum!` is because I use a code at batch start that generates random names for the .rar archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is similar to [Using a loop to rar multiple subfolders in a main folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188631/3074564) and can be therefore easily achieved with

```
@echo off
for /D %%F in ("%USERPROFILE%\mainFolder\*") do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -ep1 -mt5 -m1 -v50M -r "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\newFolder\%_RndAlphaNum%" "%%~F"
    goto Done
)
:Done
```

The command `goto Done` results in breaking FOR loop after processing first directory and continue the batch job below label `Done`.

Again command **m** is used instead of **a** to archive and then delete all files and folders packed into the archive file created directly in the destination folder.